# Updating useState from components

Tags: reactjs

I am learning ReactJS (slowly it seems) and was wondering how the below would work:

I have a search function that the user can enter a word(s) into and it spits out a load of variations of the word entered. The word is put into a button that I would like the user to be able to click and have the whole thing happen again (rather than them having to enter the name in manually).

I can't figure out how to update the useState from the NameList.js file. (I currently get the Error: React Hook "useState" cannot be called at the top level. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function) Thanks in advance!

**NameList.js**

```
export default function NamesList({ namesList }) {
    var names_generated = arrayMaker(generator(split_name(namesList.toString())))
    return (
        names_generated.map(names_generated => {
            return(
                <div className="col-4 col-xl-2 col-xxl-1">
                    <button className="sug-names">{names_generated.name}</button>
                </div>
            )
        })
    )
}
```

**Home.js**

```
export default function Home() {
  const [namesList, setNamesList] = useState([])
  const inputName = useRef()

  function getInputName(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const name = inputName.current.value
    if (name === '') return
    setNamesList([name])
  }
  return (
    <>
      <div className="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <div className="">
          <Container>
            <Form>
                <div>
                    <Form.Control ref={inputName} id="input_name" name="username" type="text" placeholder="Desired Name" />
                    <Button onClick={getInputName} variant="primary" type="submit"></Button>
                </div>
            </Form>
          </Container>
          <Container>
            <div className='row'>
              <NameList namesList={namesList} />
            </div>
          </Container>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div>0 Names Found</div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: from the error message, it seems that you called useState from outside the react component, but it is not clear in the code you provided, so providing the whole page will be  better

Answer (score 0):

I guess it happened because of two things,

**The first is that the child should not be in the form of:**

```
 “function NamesList(){}”
```

but rather must be in the form of:

```
 “const NamesList =() =>{}”
```

**and as for the parent, it must be in the form of:**

```
“function home(){}”
```

and not

```
“const NamesList = () =>{}”
```

**And the second thing is to try to delete the parentheses like this code:**

```
const NamesList = (namesList) => {
    var names_generated = arrayMaker(generator(split_name(namesList.toString())))
    return (
        names_generated.map(names_generated => {
            return(
                <div className="col-4 col-xl-2 col-xxl-1">
                    <button className="sug-names">{names_generated.name}</button>
                </div>
            )
        })
    )
}

export default NamesList ;
```

**also edit this function in Home file:**

```
  function getInputName(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const name = inputName.current.value
    if (name === '') return
    setNamesList(name)
  }
```

Comment: tell me if your problem was solved